# Evaluate $-\int_{0}^{\infty}x\sin(x)\ln(1-e^{-x})dx=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n^2+1)^2}$

Tags: integration

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty}x\sin(x)\ln(1-e^{-x})dx=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n^2+1)^2}$$

**Is there a closed form for this integral?**

I was only able to find the equivalent sum to it(How? using wolfram integrator or I did some other calculations but can't remembered)

To integrate this integral we can use integration by parts, but I don't think that is suitable for this situation. There must be a short way to evaluate this. **Can anyone give a hand here?**

---

Let see

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty}x\sin(x)\ln(1-e^{-x})dx=I$$

$$I=[-x\cos(x)+\sin(x)]\ln(1-e^{-x})-\int\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\cdot[-\cos(x)+\sin(x)]dx$$

As you can see, it is enormous.

Comment: Do you know much about contour integration?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=Sum%5B1%2F(n%5E2+%2B+1)%5E2,+%7Bn,+1,+Infinity%7D%5D) does give a closed form. It looks deeply unpleasant, but that means you can hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the identity $$ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2x}\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}
 $$ so if we assume that $x>0
 $ we get $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{x}}\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x}}\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}x}
 $$ and so $$\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi\sqrt{x}}{2}\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x}}\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+n^{2}}
 $$ then taking the derivative and taking $x=1
 $ we get $$\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi\sqrt{x}}{2}\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right)_{x=1}^{'}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{\left(1+n^{2}\right)^{2}}$$ so $$2\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{\left(1+n^{2}\right)^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi^{2}\textrm{csch}^{2}\left(\pi\right)+\pi\coth\left(\pi\right)-2\right).$$

Comment: Thank you twice @Marco Cantarini.

Comment: @mahdi You're welcome.

Comment: you found the closed form via the sum. How would you go about integrating the integral?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
First, we expand the $\ln$ function:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{-\int_{0}^{\infty}x\sin\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 -\expo{-x}}\,\dd x} & =
\Im\sum_{n = 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}x\expo{\ic x}\,{\expo{-nx} \over n}\,\dd x =
\sum_{n = 1}{1 \over n}\,\Im\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x\expo{-\pars{n - \ic}x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{{1 \over \pars{n - \ic}^{2}}}}
\\[3mm] & =
\sum_{n = 1}{1 \over n}\,\Im
\bracks{{\pars{n + \ic}^{2} \over \pars{n^{2} + 1}^{2}}} =
\color{#f00}{2\sum_{n = 1}{1 \over \pars{n^{2} + 1}^{2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is above my head, elegant answer thank you.

Comment: @mahdi You're welcome. I'm glad it was useful to you.

Comment: Felix is back!!